# Pointer Integer Character Warning in C

Tags: c, string, gcc, char, compiler-warnings

I have written a function to check if two strings are same or not.

```
int sameString (char string1[], char string2[]) {
    int i = 0;
    while (string1[i] == string2[i]) {
        if (string1[i] == "\0" || string2[i] == "\0") {
            if (string1[i] == "\0" && string2[i] == "\0") {
                return TRUE;
            }
            else {
                return FALSE;
            }
        }
        i++;
    }
}
```

It is working correctly. But, gcc compiler is giving some warnings which I didn't get.

```
2.c: In function ‘sameString’:
2.c:10:24: warning: comparison between pointer and integer [enabled by default]
         if (string1[i] == "\0" || string2[i] == "\0") {
                        ^
2.c:10:46: warning: comparison between pointer and integer [enabled by default]
         if (string1[i] == "\0" || string2[i] == "\0") {
                                              ^
2.c:11:28: warning: comparison between pointer and integer [enabled by default]
             if (string1[i] == "\0" && string2[i] == "\0") {
                            ^
2.c:11:50: warning: comparison between pointer and integer [enabled by default]
             if (string1[i] == "\0" && string2[i] == "\0") {
                                                  ^
```

Also while scanning and saving a string,

```
char operation[8];
scanf ("%s", &operation);
```

I am getting one more error, which I didn't get.

```
2.c: In function ‘main’:
2.c:65:9: warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘char (*)[8]’ [-Wformat=]
         scanf ("%s", &operation);
         ^
```

Can someone explain what are these errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, `string1[i]` is of type `char` and you're comparing that with a *string*, `"\0"`. What you need is to

```
 string1[i] == '\0'
```

and likewise.

Secondly, it's most likely that `operation` is an array. You can pass the array name as the argument of `%s` with `scanf()`, it decays to the pointer to the first element of the array, automatically.

Comment: You mean i should write scanf ("%s", &operation[0]); ?

Answer (score 1):

You must use character literals instead of string literals

```
  if (string1[i] == '\0' || string2[i] == '\0') {
                    ^^^^                  ^^^^
        if (string1[i] == '\0' && string2[i] == '\0') {
                          ^^^^                  ^^^^
            return TRUE;
        }
```

String literals as for example "\0" have types of character arrays. String literal "\0" has type `char[2]` and consists of two characters { '\0', '\0' }. 
In expressions with rare exceptions they are converted to pointers to their first characters and have type `char *`.

Take into account that in general case the function parameters should have the qualifier const.

Also there are redundant conditions inside the function.

The function can be written simpler. For example

```
int sameString ( const char string1[], const char string2[] ) 
{
    int i = 0;

    while ( string1[i] == string2[i] && string1[i] != '\0' ) i++;

    return string1[i] == string2[i];
}
```

Instead of the type `int` for the index it is better to use type `size_t` or `ptrdiff_t`.

For example

```
size_t i = 0;
```

Comment: i think it should be while ( string1[i] == string2[i] || (string1[i] != '\0' && string2[i] = '\0') ) i++; Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @rohit15079 You are wrong.

Comment: Ok Sorry I got it.

Answer (score 1):

In C, a double quoted string is a string (an array of `char`), while a single quoted string is a single character (`char`):

```
#include "stdio.h"

int main (int argc, char **argv ) {
  char* s= "foo";

  // this is comparing the character at s[0] to the location  
  // (pointer) of where the string "f" is stored.
  if (s[0] == "f") {
    printf("s[0] is the same as the location of the string f\n");
  }

  // This is comparing the character at s[0] to the character 'f'
  // which is what you're asking to do.
  if (s[0] == 'f') {
    printf("s[0] is the same as the character f\n");
  }
}
```

`gcc` is warning you because although you can do these comparisons (between different types) if you really want to, it is almost certainly not what you meant to do.